# Email from lookup field throwing error

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We recently updated our CRM 2013 update to SP1. Afterwards the lookup field on the email form taking care of the from field, throws an error when clicked on.

When running diagnostics tool and reading with trace log viewer i see following error.

```
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 7, position 58.
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
  RequestUrl: http://mypage.com/company/AppWebServices/LookupService.asmx
```

I can see that different users have created emails and used the from field after i updated to SP1. So does anyone have an idea what might cause this?

Update: If i click on the field itself and delete the user the lookup works without problem. It is only if there is allready a user in the field and i try to lookup that an error is shown.

Comment: It looks like some email addresses are being stored in header format `<blah@example.org>`  while your CRM now only wants plain address format. Sounds like a clean up job.

Comment: Since this is part of Microsofts code how exactly do i go about doing that?